# 2007 Rabbit - Intermittently wont start

Tags: electrical, starting, starter

Vehicle: 2007 VW Rabbit. Auto. 2.5L

Problem: The problem started one week ago. When starting car sometimes it will only turn over once and then silence. Solution is to wait a minute or so and then try again, usually works the second or third time. First time it happened was 5 days ago, then it happened again 3 days ago, and then it happened twice today. When the car finally does start, the 'Locked Steering Wheel' & 'Traction Control Off' lights stay on the dash for about a minute while driving.

I am trying to trouble shoot the problem, only thing I can think of is the starter motor is starting to go?

Comment: When you say, "*will only turn over once*" ... does that mean it turns over for one revolution and then quits turning over, or does it mean you can sit there and crank and crank and it will never start up? Do you know if this vehicle comes with any kind of theft deterrent system built into the key (electronic key identification)? Depending on what your first answer is, the vehicle may not be registering the key when you put it into the ignition, preventing the engine from starting. In some cars, this also give strange lights on the dash.

Comment: Hey. By turn over once I mean one revolution (Sound: 'Erruhhh'... and then nothing, no clicking, nothing).

Comment: That might be an electronic problem where the CAN bus (the network used by the controllers to communicate) suddenly goes offline; it can explain why some warning lights stay on for some time; until the controllers restore communication and return to normal operation.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a car has starting issues, the first things I check are the battery, the alternator and the starter.

You can check the battery easily with a voltmeter or take it to a shop and have them do a [load test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsJUuLu1cw0) on the battery. You can also [test the alternator with a multimeter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dq24oPUVmdA), but I prefer using amperage meter.

Once you verify those things are alright you starting looking elsewhere.

My initial suspicion is that there's a problem with the starter. Intermittent cranking sounds like the starter could be going bad. A starter is a fairly straightforward swap/fix.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a power issue. make sure you have a good connection on the battery cables. Use a multimeter set to DC volts and put one lead on the battery post and on on the battery cable connector and make sure there is no voltage drop (meter should read 0v). OR take them off and clean and retighten them. If that doesnt work check the ground connection on the body behind the driver's side headlight and make sure its clean. you will notice if you disconnect the battery you will get those same 2 lights on the dash and you have to drive to reset them.